# Python Plotly multiple charts in one single view

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I want use a for cycle to call a charting function and then represent the outcome chart into a section of a multi charting page[Example single chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvq5N.png)
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLkDO.png)

I have a charting function (see below Charting Function Section) that i recall in a the main script with a for cycle to get several charts in sequence. Now I would like to represent all the charts, in compact size (2 columns 4 rows) in one single page. In literature I find that Subplot allows me to do so but I struggle to find the right command to represent the outcome from the charting function.

I thought something like the below in the Main Section would work but it is not

---------- Main Section ---------

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


for cont in range(8):
    fig = charting_func(cont)
    fig_all.add_trace(fig,
    row=1, col=1
    ) #row and col incrementing function to be defined 
    fig_all.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
    fig_all.show()
```

----- Charting Function ------

```
def charting_func(n_chrt):
    # Arbitrarily 10 colors for up to 10 clusters
    #colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'purple','pink', 'silver']

    # Create Scatter plot, assigning each point a color where
    # point group = color index.
    fig = btc.plot.scatter(
        x=btc.index,
        y="Adj Close",
        color=[colors[i] for i in lists_clusters[n_chrt]],
        title="k-values = {0}".format(n_chrt+2)
    )

    # Add horizontal lines 
    for cluster_avg in output[n_chrt][1:-1]:
        fig.add_hline(y=cluster_avg, line_width=1, line_color="blue")

    # Add a trace of the price for better clarity
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=btc.index,
        y=btc['Adj Close'],
        line_color="black",
        line_width=1
    ))
    # Make it pretty
    layout = go.Layout(
        plot_bgcolor='#D9D9D9',
        showlegend=False,
        # Font Families
        font_family='Monospace',
        font_color='#000000',
        font_size=20,
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeslider=dict(
                visible=False
            ))
    )
    fig.update_layout(layout)
    return fig
```

type here

Answer (score 0):

The basic form of a subplot is to add a location arrangement to the graph setup. So the functionalization needs to have matrix information or something like that. I have no data to present, so I have taken the stock prices of 4 companies and graphed them. As for the clustering by price, it is not included in the code, so the binning process is used to get the values and labels for the horizontal line. Please rewrite this part to your own logic. If you are good enough, the functionalization should work well.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import itertools
import yfinance as yf

stock = ['TSLA','MSFT','AAPL','AMD']
#fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=['MSFT','TSLA','AMD','AAPL'])

for s,rc in zip(stock, itertools.product([1,2],[2,1])):
    #print(s, rc[0], rc[1])
    df = yf.download(s, start="2017-09-01", end="2022-04-01", interval='1mo', progress=False)
    colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'orange']
    s_cut, bins = pd.cut(df['Adj Close'], 5, retbins=True, labels=colors)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers+lines',
                             x=df.index,
                             y=df['Adj Close'],
                             marker=dict(
                                 size=10,
                                 color=s_cut.tolist()
                             )),
                  row=rc[0], col=rc[1]
                 )
    for b in bins[1:-1]:
        fig.add_hline(y=b, line_width=1, line_color="blue", row=rc[0], col=rc[1])

fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=600, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so you go one step earlier the charting. In the sense that I could use the data already collected in a list thanks this is really useful.
Happy 2023 BTW